# What is a good (folding) poker table for home usage?

Tags: equipment

Every month I have a poker evening at my home with friends. Until now we played just on a common table (not poker table).

Now I want buy something like a folding poker table. But I am not sure if this is a good idea or if I should spend much more money for a real poker table.

I have limited space so I thought a folding poker table is good enough - but I am not sure, because of this one folding line, marked red in the picture. Do cards stuck there or is this 'break' in the table no problem?

Do you have any experiences with such folding poker tables and can recommend them?

[image]

Comment: It realy depends on the quality of the table. I played in many tables and some of them had problem because of that fold. When you dealt cards they would stuck there or turn around. But since you only play once a month i'd still recommend you to take that one since it's pretty cheap. There's still the possibility to buy a poker mat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the one you want, it even looks sexy:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Folding-Seater-Effect-Racetrack-Casino/dp/B008D2C9NS

[image: table photo]

Comment: Wow this one looks really good!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tables on Amazon.  Here is just one link.

[http://www.amazon.com/Green-Octogan-Poker-Table-Brybelly/dp/B000GBI4MY/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1393879412&sr=8-7&keywords=poker+table](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GBI4MY)

Answer (score 0):

Build your own :),  if your table is big enough just buy some filz.

I did the same. For some bucks I bought 2 different colors. 
There are some nice sellers located in germany.
It  will not take too much space when its not in use. a Poker plate or table will always be big, even if foldet.

Comment: Well, actually I am building my own table with rail, track race and playing surface. I tested this folding table and it was quite nice. Better than a plain table. As soon as I am done with my table, I will write here a tutorial.

Comment: and an invitation to play with you would be sexy.

Comment: if you still live in berlin :)

Comment: Yes, I do. Playing in PokerLounge and Potsdamer Platz. As soon as the table is build I'll post it and will invite for weekly games :)

Comment: Table's ready and first rounds are played ;)

Comment: excellent, feel free to invite me. my google mail account is the same name as here.